# Symbolizing field with many values in Mapbox Studio?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-studio

I am using Mapbox Studio and trying to symbolize my Tileset which has about 200 unique values.

I am able to create individual 'stops' and manually assign a unique color, but looking for a more efficient way to symbolize each of these 200 values without having to touch each value manually.

**What I've tried**

- I can easily create unique symbology in ArcGIS and QGIS, but Mapbox does not appear to accept such formats.
- Searching Mapbox's documentation to see if I can apply a unique default color symbology for each unique value, but haven't found such a process.
- Searched GIS Stack Exchange and StackOverflow, but haven't found such a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QGIS you would do this by choosing a color ramp (or random) and hitting Classify, Mapbox Studio doesn't yet offer this feature but in the meantime if you choose the "Edit property as JSON" at the bottom (after choosing Set value by data):

[image]

[image]

Here you can insert a large list of stops.

You could write a program to build that small JSON either using random colours, random colours with a check to ensure it's not too close to a colour already selected, using [color brewer colours](http://colorbrewer2.org/#type=qualitative&scheme=Paired&n=12)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, using 'Edit Property as JSON' did the trick!  I actually went to the following site and indicated the number of random colors - http://tools.medialab.sciences-po.fr/iwanthue/index.php.  Then I inserted the list of stops as you recommended and it worked perfectly.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing bad with Mapbox Studio, but I would go in another direction:
 I would install QGIS 2.18(free open source), which can manage the 200 unique values style easily.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHcq15Ytqj8

and then to put it in the web use some of the plugins like:

qgiscloud

qgis2web

Than other servers could do the same but is more difficult

www.mapserver.org

geoserver.org

Comment: Totally agree and a huge QGIS fan, but limited to Mapbox as the platform and looking for anyway to import something from ESRI, QGIS, etc into Mapbox with predefined styling.

Comment: @pac_co have you tried https://github.com/boundlessgeo/lib-mapboxgl-qgis ?